# How Do I print following pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, text, console

How do I print text in following style to a C# console application?

```
1111111
 22222
  333
   4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what style are you referring to???

Comment: 1111111
  22222
    333
      4

Comment: Should be in triangle style upside down.

Comment: Your post was misformatted, hope my edit gets accepted soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upright triangle:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    const int height = 4;
    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        //left padding
        for(int col = 0; col < height - row - 1; col++) {
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
        //digits
        for(int col = 0; col < row * 2 + 1; col++) {
            Console.Write((char)('1' + row));
        }
        //right padding (is this needed?)
        for(int col = 0; col < height - row - 1; col++) {
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

*Prints:*

```
   1   
  222  
 33333 
4444444
```

---

**Upside-down triangle:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    const int height = 4;
    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        //left padding
        for(int col = 0; col < row; col++) {
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
        //digits
        for(int col = 0; col < (height - row) * 2 - 1; col++) {
            Console.Write((char)('1' + row));
        }
        //right padding (is this needed?)
        for(int col = 0; col < row; col++) {
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

*Prints:*

```
1111111
 22222 
  333  
   4
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this :-)

Comment: Will you be able to show me an example of how to display it in other way as well ?

  1
 22
333

Thanks

Comment: What other way do you mean?

Comment: just like the normal triangle without upside down.